# HI In Codename one I created a button on my form but when I click on the Button it does not perform the Action Event

Tags: java, codenameone

I Created a button on my codename one frm but when I click on the button it does not perform the Action Event. I tried removing the Button and to recreate but it does not work.

Comment: Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: What type of platform are using? Is this Android, or JavaFX, or Spring, or something else? Please update your question with a lot more detail and some code.

Comment: HI I am using Netbeans JAVA and I compile it to codename one

Comment: @CurtisWhite see the [codenameone](https://www.codenameone.com) tag

Answer (score 0):

Using something like:

```
Button b = new Button("My Button");
myForm.add(b);
b.addActionListner(e -> {
     ToastBar.showInfoMessage("Hi There");
});
```

Works for me.